# Gerrit Rest API - Gitiles Plugin: Get commit details, list of committed files

Tags: git, gerrit

I'm writing a python script to fetch the list of commits and its committed file information. I've the following API to fetch the list of commit logs,

```
/plugins/gitiles/repo_name/+log/master/?format=JSON

Response:
    {
        'log': [{
            'commit': 'b56e709904e45e1d70808397b46c972412341a87',
            'tree': 'd11122d07dd027bacc08b4c2cd79101292ce70bc',
            'parents': ['66dff5626a437eb0e8496044d2e507696d1e614c'],
            'author': {
                'name': 'Test User',
                'email': 'testuser@example.com',
                'time': 'Sat Aug 03 19:07:04 2019 -0700'
            },
            'committer': {
                'name': 'Test User',
                'email': 'testuser@example.com',
                'time': 'Sat Aug 03 19:07:04 2019 -0700'
            },
            'message': 'Test commit message\n\nChange-Id: Ic9f5f98819a78beacef577759f22d0fca0229746\n'
        }]
    }
```

Now, I want to get the list of files under a specific commit. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You could try Gerrit's own api `/changes/?q=commit:${commit}&o=ALL_FILES&o=ALL_REVISIONS`, where `${commit}` is the full hash.

Comment: Actually, it returns an empty array since I am not using code review. I'll directly push the changes to master and here is where I see the changes, `http://11.0.0.209:8080/plugins/gitiles/repo_name/`

Comment: We have a similar task, in which we use `paramiko` to log onto the gerrit slave server and run git commands to retrieve data. There might be some options for gitile apis to get the file list. But I can't find any documentation about it.